# Scipy FFT Frequency Analysis of very noisy signal

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, fft

I have noisy [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3hdaej7io32vycb/signal.xlsx?dl=0) for which I want to calculate frequency and amplitude. The samples were collected every 1/100th sec. From trends, I believe frequency to be ~ 0.3

[image]

When I use `numpy` `fft` module, I end up getting very high frequency (36.32 /sec) which is clearly not correct. I tried to filter the data with `pandas` `rolling_mean` to remove the noise before fft, but that too didn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import fft
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Moisture_mean_x = pd.read_excel("signal.xlsx", header = None)
Moisture_mean_x = pd.rolling_mean(Moisture_mean_x, 10) # doesn't helps
Moisture_mean_x = Moisture_mean_x.dropna()
Moisture_mean_x = Moisture_mean_x -Moisture_mean_x.mean()
frate = 100. #/sec           
Hn = fft.fft(Moisture_mean_x)
freqs = fft.fftfreq(len(Hn), 1/frate)
idx = np.argmax(np.abs(Hn))
freq_in_hertz = freqs[idx]
```

Can someone guide me how to fix this?

Comment: 1) the code is fine. 2) why are you expecting 0.3 Hz? I count 6/8 peaks in 2500 seconds, for an estimate of a dominant low-freq of about 0.0024 to 0.0032 Hz. 3) What's wrong with 36.32 Hz, i.e. why are you sure this is not correct? 4) If you really want to prefilter the signal with a rolling mean, choose a window size different from 1. As it is now, the call to `rolling_mean()` is doing nothing.

Comment: @gg349 I assume the picture is showing 2500 samples, not 2500 seconds. That makes your range 0.24 to 0.32 Hz which certainly contains 0.3.

Comment: @MarkRansom well spotted

Comment: sorry, it was typo with `rolling_mean`, fixed it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right there is something wrong. One needs to explictiy ask pandas for the zeroth column:

```
Hn = np.fft.fft(Moisture_mean_x[0])
```

Else something wrong happen, which you can see by the fact that the FFT result was not symetric, which should be the case for real input.

[image: result]

Comment: Indeed. And, now no filtering is needed as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Seems like *@tillsten* already answered your question, but here is some additional confirmation.  The first plot is your data (zero mean and I changed it to a csv). The second is the power spectral density and you can see a fat mass with a peak at ~0.3 Hz.  I 'zoomed' in on the third plot to see if there was a second hidden frequency close to the main frequency.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

x = pd.read_csv("signal.csv")
x = np.array(x, dtype=float)[:,0]
x = x - np.mean(x)
fs = 1e2

f, Pxx = signal.welch(x, fs, nperseg=1024)
f_res, Pxx_res = signal.welch(x, fs, nperseg=2048)

plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(x)

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(f, Pxx)
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.xlabel('frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('PSD')

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(f_res, Pxx_res)
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.xlabel('frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('PSD')

plt.show()

Hn = fft.fft(x)
freqs = fft.fftfreq(len(Hn), 1/fs)
idx = np.argmax(np.abs(Hn))
freq_in_hertz = freqs[idx]
print 'Main freq:', freq_in_hertz
print 'RMS amp:', np.sqrt(Pxx.max())
```

This prints:

```
Main freq: 0.32012805122
RMS amp: 0.0556044913489
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I noticed the hidden frequency as well. So, I calculate mean frequency as:     `freqs =   fft.fftfreq(len(Hn), 1/frate) ;
    ind = np.arange(1,len(Hn)/2+1 ) ;
    psd = np.abs(Hn[ind])**2+ np.abs(Hn[-ind])**2 ;
    cut = 0.7*psd.max() ;
    ind1 =  np.where(psd > cut) ;
    freq_in_hertz = freqs[ind[ind1]].mean()`.

Comment: That works.  You can also find the second peak by `idx =np.argmax(np.abs(Hn)[:5])`
`freq_in_hertz = freqs[idx]` and it turns out to be 0.16006402561 (exactly half 0.32012...).

Answer (score 1):

An FFT is a filter bank.  Just look for the magnitude peak **only** within the expected frequency range in the FFT result (instead of the entire result vector), and most of the other spectrum will essentially be filtered out.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of that as well, but I just gave only one sample for the question here, while I have hundreds of such signals to be analyzed. Selecting expected frequency range manually will be very tedious. Is there a better way to self-calculate this frequency range?

Comment: You can't filter without knowing what frequencies to try to remove (and thus what's left).  Even a moving average is a (low-quality) filter.  So you have to know what range to expect, or leave the noisy result unfiltered, and take what you get.

Comment: I understand moving average is a low-quality filter, but I expected it will lead me closer to the expected frequency. But, even if I used `rolling mean(...,100)` which gives me pretty smoothened signal[1], the result remain 34.8 Hz! This gives me feel that I am missing something. [1]https://www.dropbox.com/s/75e0pgdcdzue9a5/smooth_signal.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary to filter the signal beforehand, because the FFT *is* a filter. Just skip those parts of the FFT that correspond to frequencies you know to contain a lot of noise - zero them out, or otherwise exclude them.

Comment: No, you don't have to. The signal is real-valued, so studying as well the negative frequency component is redundant and will lead to the same result.

Comment: @gg349 absolutely correct, I didn't realize FFT was returning complex values not real.  I'll remove the inaccurate parts of this answer, which should be most of it.

Comment: @MarkRansom I agree, and this seems to be the only solution so far. But, I wonder even if I completely noise the [signal](http://dropbox.com/s/75e0pgdcdzue9a5/smooth_signal.png?dl=0) to calculate the frequency, the result remain 34.8 Hz! This gives me feeling that I am missing some steps in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you.

https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ButterworthBandpass.html

You should filter only the band around the expected frequency and improve the signal noise ratio before applying the FFT.

Edit:

Mark Ransom gave a smarter answer, if you have to do the FFT you can just cut off the noise after the transformation. It won't give a worse result than a filter would.

Comment: Why do you have to filter? Mark Ransom comment to the other similar post. Why would a value of 10 lead to a geometric mean?

Comment: Sorry, it was typo. I had tried `rolling_mean( .., 10)` and got 36.4 Hz.

Comment: Argh, you are right, the answer of Mark is the smartest. I misunderstood the data in the request. Actually I don't get why his answer has been down voted. +1

Answer (score -1):

You should use a low pass filter, which should keep the larger periodic variations and smooth out some of the higher frequency stuff first. After that, then can do FFT to get the peaks. Here is a [recipe for FIR filter](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/FIRFilter.html) typically used for this exact sort of thing.

Comment: Filtering is completely redundant, the FFT is splitting stuff up by frequency already. It's just necessary to ignore those parts of the FFT result that correspond to frequencies outside of the range of interest.